# Exportar datagridview con imágenes a un excel, sin ruta para la imagen

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día a todos, espero me pudiesen ayudar con este caso, quiero exportar a un excel un datagridview que contiene imágenes, pero en base de datos me las guarda con este formato 0xFFD8... y quisiera que en excel en la parte de

```
worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(ms, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 32, 32);
```

justo en este primer parámetro me pide la ubicación de la imagen, pero cómo tal no se guarda en una ruta.

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            // see the excel sheet behind the program  
            app.Visible = true;
            // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.  
            // store its reference to worksheet  
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Hoja1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            // changing the name of active sheet  
            worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
            // storing header part in Excel  
            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
            for (int i = 0; i < DgvPersonas.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DgvPersonas.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (DgvPersonas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.GetType() == typeof(byte[]))
                    {
                        Image image1 = byteArrayToImage((byte[])DgvPersonas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        image1.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1];
                        float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
                        float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);
                        worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(ms, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 32, 32);
                        oRange.RowHeight = 36;
                        //File.Delete(@"D:\test.PNG");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = DgvPersonas.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }

                }
            }
            workbook.SaveAs("d:\\output.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        }
```

Comment: y si la guardas en una carpeta a modo de temporal ??

Comment: Hola, cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: En `image1.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);` en vez de colocar un `MemoryStream` como primer argumento, colacas la rura, algo como `image1.Save(@"D:\test.PNG", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: Hola, le hice así, pero cuando descargo el Excel me marca que no se encontró ningún archivo.

Comment: Error en esta línea: worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\Temp\test.PNG", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, 32, 32);

Comment: verifica que `C:\\Temp\test.PNG` exista y me avisas

Comment: Hola, ya me exporta el excel a medias, porque cuando va a exportar la tercer imagen de la tercer fila del datagrid me aparece un error: workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\\Temp\output.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); Me sale el mensaje: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No se ha podido acceder al archivo.